# Images not loading on windows

Tags: html, css

When I test my code on apple everything loads properly but when I test it on windows only two out of five images load?
I've tried to fix it by rewriting the code but it still doesn't work.

```
<section class="features">
            <figure>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Contact/twitter.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Jonathan on Twitter"></a>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Contact/facebook.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Jonathan on Facebook"></a>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/JonathanDoesStuff" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Contact/youtube.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Jonathan on Youtube"></a>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="https://discord.gg/MvVR5KS" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Contact/discord.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Jonathan on Discord"></a>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="mailto:%20jonathandoeswork@gmail.com" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Contact/mail.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Contact Jonathan Via Email"></a>
            </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: where do I find the dev tools?

Comment: Dev tools: `F12`.

Comment: everything looks good

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was happening because of an adblocker.